# Как поставить now() вместо null через Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

У меня есть такое поле:

```
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
```

Проблема в том, что `Hibernate` всегда явным образом подпихивает в него `null`, а мне надо, чтобы срабатывало `NOW()`. Так не получается (все равно приходит `null`):

```
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default now()")
private Date createdAt;
```

Если сделать `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL`, то когда не указано поле `created_at` ошибка `ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint`.

Как сделать это правильно ?

Comment: [@CreationTimestamp](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CreationTimestamp.html) или заполнять поле в методе помеченным `@PrePersist` . Но тут дата будет создаваться в коде, а не средствами БД.

Comment: @Akina Я использую `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: Тогда коммент снимается.

Comment: @faoxis для PostgreSQL: `columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone default now()"`, взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42400146/6752984), но не проверял

Comment: @MrFylypenko эммм... а чем это отличается от того, что написано у меня ?

Comment: @faoxis наличием `with time zone`

Comment: Решение задачи найдено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Date createdAt;
```

Comment: Это решает задачу?
Как это описать при помощи xml?